# CSS - Reposition elements without altering HTML

Tags: html, css

For the life of me I can't get this to work how I would like. I've got an image inside of a link and a span around the text. All I'm trying to do is get the image floated to the right of the text and the text to be vertically aligned center next to it. I CAN'T change the mark-up and the image could be any size so simply using a margin-top won't work.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sppbe4j5/

HTML:

```
<div>
 <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <span>Some Text</span>            
 </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{ display: table; }

a img {
  display: table-cell;
  float:right;
}

a {
  display: table-cell;
}

a span{ 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Just a side-note: Floating a table-cell doesn't make sense at all. The computed `display` value would be `block` in this case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sppbe4j5/1/

Comment: side-note2: You shouldn't design a `display: table-cell` inside another `display: table-cell`

Comment: Your question is really not about vertical aligning, but about re-ordering the position of elements dynamically. The title is kind of misleading IMO.

Comment: @DelmonYoung- I had forgotten about `direction`. Posted an answer using that...

Comment: @LcSalazar Thanks for the info! Didn't even think of doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually vertical alignment can be done simply by giving `vertical-align: middle` to the inline-level elements ,`img` and the `span`.

Hence the real question is how to re-order the position of elements without altering the HTML.

Personally, I'd go with Flexbox layout if it is possible. However if supporting **IE9** is a concern, you could fake the effect by using CSS transform. Simply by rotating the container clockwise and rotating individual elements anticlockwise or vise versa.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/sppbe4j5/4/)**

```css
a.container {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(180deg); 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.container img, a.container span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

*Verndor prefixes omitted due to brevity.*

```css
a.container {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg); 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.container img, a.container span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#" class="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <span>Some Text</span>            
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @DelmonYoung Don't mention it :-) Also it would be great if you could update the title of the question to indicate the actual problem. Thank you.

Comment: @HashemQolami - I had forgotten about `direction`. Posted an answer using that...

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this by using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) layout and [flex order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) like this:

```css
a {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
a span {
    order: 1;
    align-self: center;
}
a img {
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <span>Some Text</span>            
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea. For reference, [browser compatibility of flexbox may be limited](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It needs to be compatible in IE9 and IE8 though. So I don't think this example works.

Comment: @MaryMelody +1 from me too. Really respect your knowledge in css :)

Comment: Any other ideas @MaryMelody :)

Comment: Nice idea Mary. @DelmonYoung I have another idea but it won't work in IE8. I was about to post it as an answer but it seems pointless.

Comment: Sorry @HashemQolami IE9 and above. It's okay if it doesn't work in IE8 :)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a closed post, but if anyone looks for this kind of question, here's another solution (better than transform, as the accepted answer)

It's possible to invert the position of the elements using the `direction` property. Then a table layout would make them vertically aligned:

**rtl - stands for *right to left***

```css
a {
    display: table;
    direction: rtl;
}

a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}

a span{ 
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <span>Some Text</span>            
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice catch, I had forgotten `direction` as well. In addition, you could omit Table layout: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/sppbe4j5/9/

Comment: True... Higher compatibility

Answer (score 0):

add this to a span:

```
   a span{
     line-height: 150px;
     height: 150px;
   }
```

Comment: This works for this specific case, but is not very flexible if (for example) the image dimensions change.